# Books or other Resources on Business Benefits from GIS?

Tags: business, references, industry

I believe [Top unsung business benefits for GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/top-unsung-business-benefits-for-gis) is an excellent source of info.

My question expands on that for any industry books related to this subject.  I know there have already been several postings for recommended books but I am trying to find books that explicitly explain the value of GIS to a company.

In short, I am looking for books that will clearly explain the business benefits (financial and otherwise) that GIS can provide for a company.

Are there are any resources on the web for this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI has devoted a lot of time and documentation to this subject.

[Here](http://www.esri.com/getting-started/executives/index.html) is a jump "on" page that should lead to plenty of case studies, and ROI (return on investment) calculators.